# Fourier application in biology

Tags: fourier-analysis

Can you tell me a biological problem which will be solved only by using Fourier series? Please bring the problem here and mention to its solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oscillation phenomena are abundant in biology (e.g. cell cycle, circadian rhythms) and Fourier analysis is very helpful, or sometimes requisite, for analyzing them.

The following is a recent paper in PNAS that explores this concept in the system of P53-Mdm2 oscillation in human cells. (P53 is a very famous tumor suppressor gene, and Mdm2 is another protein that degrades P53.)

http://www.pnas.org/content/107/30/13550.abstract
http://lahav.med.harvard.edu/publications/Geva-Zatorsky2010.pdf